# React production build failed to load

Tags: reactjs

I have built some code with React. During its "development build", `npm start` at `localhost:3000` give me the correct behavior.

However, after `npm run build` and `serve -s build`, the site at `localhost:5000` give me this error: `Can't remove headers after they are sent`.

I have tried to take out everything and make it a bare bone project but the error still appears.

[image]

I have tried the production build before and this just happened.

Comment: Looks like it's not react related. Instead, look into server stack. Looks like you are trying to manipulate headers on already sent response.

Comment: But development mode can run? So there must be something different between prod mode and dev mode?

Comment: Yep, exactly. There must be difference in prod/dev mode

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**:

Nothing serious. I reinstalled `serve` package and it is now OK. Seems that a recent update to `serve` (`npm i -g serve`) got broken and after reinstall `serve` package, it is now OK.